# deploying Django project -beginner

Tags: python, django, webdeploy, pythonanywhere

please help me I'm a beginner and this is the first time I want to deploy a website I want to use pythonanywhere but I don't know which folders of my project I have to upload hm trying to deploy the site for hours but going nowhere please help
this is my source :
inside my main project, I have this folder [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItVIH.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItVIH.png)

[image]

please help me how can i deploy my site

Comment: This is the best video I've found for deploying to PythonAnywhere, it's incredibly useful: https://youtu.be/SCoGwHCNXVw

Comment: There is a step by step tutorial on PythonAnywhere help pages for that. Try reading it: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DeployExistingDjangoProject/

Answer (score 0):

Check out this video as it provides an in-depth step by step way to upload your Django project to pythonanywhere - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SCoGwHCNXVw. You need to upload the entire project folder and then specify the path to your folder containing the settings file and the path to your folder containing the entire file structure in the WSGI configuration file as shown in the video (around the 12:10 mark).